# How can I return a stream rather than writing to disk?

Tags: c#, openxml-sdk

I am using OpenXML SDK.

The OpenXML SDK creates a method called CreatePackage as such:

```
public void CreatePackage(string filePath)
{
    using (SpreadsheetDocument package = SpreadsheetDocument.Create(filePath,               SpreadsheetDocumentType.Workbook))
    {
        CreateParts(package);
    }
}
```

I call it from my program as follows which will create the Excel file to a given path:

```
gc.CreatePackage(excelFilePath);
Process.Start(_excelFilePath);
```

I am not sure how to tweak the code such that it gives back a Stream which shows the Excel file vs having it create the file on disk.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the [documentation for `SpreadsheetDocument.Create`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/documentformat.openxml.packaging.spreadsheetdocument.create.aspx) there are multiple overloads, one of which takes a `Stream`.

so change your code to:

```
public void CreatePackage(Stream stream)
{
    using (SpreadsheetDocument package = SpreadsheetDocument.Create(stream,               SpreadsheetDocumentType.Workbook))
    {
        CreateParts(package);
    }
}
```

And then call it with any valid `Stream`, for example:

```
using(var memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
{
   CreatePackage(memoryStream);
   // do something with memoryStream
}
```

Comment: Thanks Jamiec, how would I open up a file (that is not stored on disk) from this memomorySteam? I tried:                 //byte[] bytes = new byte[memoryStream.Length];
                //memoryStream.Read(bytes, 0, (int)memoryStream.Length);
                //file.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
                //file.Close();
                //memoryStream.Close(); but that did not do it